# Convert an array of promises to one promise that could be one of included types: [P<string>, P<number>] -> Promise<string | number>

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function that will return the first settled value from an array of Promises

```js
const firstSettledValue = (...promises: Array<Promise<any>>): Promise<any> {
   // ...
}

const v = firstSettledValue(
  new Promise<string>(),
  new Promise<number>(),
  new Promise<boolean>()
)

v // Promise<string | number | boolean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a we can use TypeScript's [Generic Rest Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#generic-rest-parameters) to handle this precisely.

This allows use to declare a generic tuple type that captures the individual type of each argument when the function is called.

Let's break it down.

First we will capture the type of each of argument passed to the function

```
const firstSettledValue = <P extends Promise<any>[]>(...promises: P) => {}

const v = firstSettledValue(
  Promise.resolve('Hello World'),
  Promise.resolve(15),
  Promise.resolve(false)
)
```

Now, we can obtain a union type of all each of all the arguments, that is the elements of `P`, by via `P[number]`.

```
type U = P[number] // string | number | boolean
```

Note that in the above `P[0]` is the type `string`, `P[1]` is the type `number`, and so on.

However, we can't use `P[Number]` directly in the above code because our elements are promises and we need to extract their value types.

To do that, we can introduce a little helper type

```
type ValueType<T> = T extends Promise<infer U>
  ? U
  : T;
```

Given a `Promise<T>`, the helper above produces `T`.

Finally we compose these techniques together

```
const firstSettledValue = <P extends Promise<any>[]>(...promises: P): Promise<ValueType<P[number]>> => {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) % promises.length;
  return promises[randomIndex];
};

const v = firstSettledValue(
  Promise.resolve('Hello World'),
  Promise.resolve(15),
  Promise.resolve(false)
);

type ValueType<T> = T extends Promise<infer U>
  ? U
  : T;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwE7QMoFMpQDboCYBqAhtgK7owC8MAPAAozoAeU6YeEMdSIAtghHQ0iYAJ4A+ANoBdcQAoAdEoAOPfoIgAuLgEpt3PgKHEy6ACqjlQupLCleAI3RJZ4qm4DeAWABQMGKCQsEgieHwAkuzMVDAAskRQABYKcNggIEhy8UkKIex8cjowAFQwAIwADBVFAKQwqoYaCrhgAOZJANy+-kiYpEhg9WpGEJJ5YbyReMzSXT4AvnO+gdAwAG4xiChQGFi4hCTkct1cw4K56BAg2GvocgDkABLo2GkwAOoZ2Hj3OgA0JwM6nQFyuNzuZQArP9AWcQb0wbc5HASIIdL4dEsfGsFEk2HIVtcQWlWpjfL4oJYKCZyBYrDQzG5qGZGCw2BxTo0hAgwHBnDAAKriE4AfkFJ20Zg6QA)

And we are done. `v` has type `Promise<string | number | boolean>`, based on the promises specified in the call.

Comment: Fantastic explanation. Thank you very much for this

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`Promise.race()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race):

```
const v = Promise.race([
  new Promise<string>(() => {}),
  new Promise<number>(() => {}),
  new Promise<boolean>(() => {})
]);

v // Promise<string | number | boolean>
```

The return type is inferred correctly.